# I'm not understanding register values surrounding multiplication code

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have been teaching myself Assembly using the tutorialspoint guide to learning NASM assembly, however I have run into some problems when trying to write code that will multiply two user-inputted numbers together. I am running into errors and I think this might also be a problem of not fully understanding how assembly architecture works regarding registers, stacks, and data segments. If I could receive help, first in understanding what is causing the errors in my code, and then in finding resources to better grasp nasm assembly, I would be very grateful.

Here is my code:

```
    write equ 4
    read equ 3
    stdout equ 1
    stdin equ 0


    section .text
        global _start

    _start:
        mov eax, write
        mov ebx, stdout
        mov ecx, msg1
        mov edx, len1
        int 80h

        mov eax, read
        mov ebx, stdin
        mov ecx, num1
        mov edx, 2
        int 80h

        mov eax, write
        mov ebx, stdout
        mov ecx, msg2
        mov edx, len2
        int 80h

        mov eax, read
        mov ebx, stdin
        mov ecx, num2
        mov edx, 2
        int 80h

        mov al, num1
        mov dl, num2
        imul dl

        mov [res], al

        mov eax, write
        mov ebx, stdout
        mov ecx, res
        mov edx, 4
        int 80h

        mov eax, 1
        int 80h

    section .bss
        num1 resb 2
        num2 resb 2
        res resb 4

    section .data
        msg1 db "Please input your first value: "
        len1 equ $-msg1
        msg2 db "Please input your second value: "
        len2 equ $-msg2
```

and here is the error I am receiving:

```
    main.o: In function `_start':                                                                                                                                                                                           

    main.asm:(.text+0x59): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.bss'                                                                                                                                              

    main.asm:(.text+0x5b): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.bss'
```

I have also tried using `mul` in place of `imul`. Thank you.

Comment: The read system call returns the characters typed, not a number. You should provide enough space for the characters you expect the user to type, including the newline, so two bytes is too small, unless you expect only one digit numbers.

Then, you need to convert the string into a number in order to perform arithmetic.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you also need to convert the result of the multiplication back to a string in order to print it.

Comment: @prl how would I go about adding more space for the numbers? I tried changing the resb to resw to reserve two words instead but the program spits out garbage characters when I input two digit numbers

Comment: The garbage characters is because the result of the multiplication isn't an ASCII character. You need to read about ASCII conversions for numbers.

Comment: @prl I followed your advice, subtracted '0' before the arithmetic and added '0' to the result. It now works with anything that produces a one digit result but gives a random character when the result is two digits.

Comment: Because you're only writing one digit into res. If you want two digits, you have to compute the two digits of the result and add '0' to each of them.

Comment: It's not *random* character, check the ASCII table, for example for result `17` you output `A` I guess (17 + 48 = 65, and that is ASCII code for uppercase A).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code

```
    mov al, num1
    mov dl, num2
    imul dl
```

says to move the address of num1 into al and the address of num2 into dl. The error is because the addresses of these variables don't fit into 8-bit registers.

What you actually want to do is move the values:

```
    mov al, [num1]
    mov dl, [num2]
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually clarifies some questions I had about registers. Namely register values versus register addresses

Comment: al and dl are registers. They don't have addresses. num1 and num2 are memory locations, which have addresses and values.